# What does & (ampersand) mean next to the attribute in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have following piece of code in TypeScript.

```
ref = (&scope:ILinkService) => {
```

What does the & mean in TypeScript/JavaScript?

Comment: ...there's no `&` in there.

Comment: Do you possibly mean the `$`?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything it's just a naming convention.

Lots of people use it with jQuery like below;

```
var ele = document.getElementById("")
var $ele = jQuery(ele);
```

Angular js uses it too in its examples

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything in TypeScript/JavaScript.

In `AngularJS` it is used to signify services that *angular* injects.